# open cash drawer using java wthont printer

Tags: java, printing, usb, libusb, usb-drive

H all,
I'm making a software in the Java standard edition and this application will have a cash drawer with adapter usb, but I have no idea how to open the cash drawer to give the returns from java. I need your help .. 
Thanks e cash drawer in java code? wthont printer

Comment: ??? Check with the manufacturer. May-be they have a how-to website.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check what USB device class the cash drawer implements. internet search yields that cash drawers often implement Virtual COM port (USB CDC ACM device class) or USB HID device class (Human Interface device). if you are on linux you can check this using `lsusb -v` on windows you can check which driver is loaded for the cash drawer in the Device Manager.

if it implements a Virtual COM port you can communicate with the cash drawer using standard RS-232 protocol (serial port), if it implements USB HID you have to use USB HID protocol (HID reports,...)